# Use plotly in Google Colab to plot dataset with more than 6M rows

Tags: python, plotly, google-colaboratory

Let me give you some context first. I was able to import a kaggle competition (m5 accuracy) whole data and works really great. The problem is that when I try to do a histogram using plotly (without agregations) doesn't return anything. But when I am using a Sample it plots properly.

Some additional info:

- I used plotly's renderer for google colab.
- The number of rows in the dataframe is 56M and my sample of 10M.
- I ran matplotlib and seaborn histograms and display successfully  histograms based on all data.
- I tried to run the histogram with a smaller dataframe with 6M. The same situation occurs but i was able to plot with a 2M sample.
- I tried a histogram with tips dataframe from seaborn and plots properly the histogram.
- When graphs based on aggregations are created it works perfectly.

Here is the link to my code. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uMU3ctDzkGObYeCfxF36hURT9WIvnrl7?usp=sharing

I know this is not a limitation for doing a well design analysis, but I am wondered if is possible to use all data available and what is creating this problem. Thank you for reading me.

Answer (score 1):

It's already in an issue [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly_express/issues/139)

The solution is to do aggregation first, e.g. collections.Counter(). Then plot a barchart instead.

Comment: Ok, interesting info in the link, thank you. But why is this happening? I mean I am using a 10M (of 56M ) sample and works perfect but when I use a 6M rows doesn't work. I understand that the problem in the link is due google Chrome crashed but that's not the current situation. Let me know if I am wrong and thanks for your time. How is possible to plot 10M sample rows and not be able to plot 6M?

Comment: It may depend on your memory status. You can try restart your computer. Then test with 6M again.